# Парсинг JSON объекта JAVA

Tags: java, json

Приходит сразу объект, я не знаю ключей.

```
{
"Ключ": Значение,
"Ключ2": Значение,
"Ключ3": Значение
}
```

Я не понимаю, как его парсить, помогите тугодуму :)
Мне нужно вывести и ключ и значение.

Comment: что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON может содержать значения и коллекции значений. Алгоритм парсинга в упрощенном виде такой:

1. Берем следующий элемент
2. Если он не коллекция - выводим его имя и значение
3. Если коллекция - берем его вложенный первый элемент и повторяем с п. 1

Пример JSON с коллекцией:

```
{
"name" : "abc" ,
"email id " : ["abc@gmail.com","def@gmail.com","ghi@gmail.com"]
}
```

---

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory(); 
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory); 
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// convert JSON string to Map
map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});

System.out.println(map);
```

где `json` - это `File`, `InputStream`, `Reader` или `String`.

Comment: У меня есть ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object> list и мне нужно засунуть в него эти ключи и значения в цикле с привязкой к тэгу, например:
hm = new HashMap<>();
                hm.put(NAME, "КЛЮЧ");
                hm.put(VALUE, "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ");
                list.add(hm);

Comment: Последний кусок кода, после слов "Еще можно так", как раз для этого. Только не в `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`, а в `HashMap<String, Object>`. Кладите в `map` и потом ваши `map`ы складывайте в `List` или еще что-нибудь с ними делайте. *P.S. Ответ немного дополнил.*

Comment: Извините, но я не понимаю как это сделать...В конце концов мне этот ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> надо засунуть в адаптер и вывести это в ListView.

Comment: @expertgames, что-то у вас лишнее нагромождение получается. Зачем пхать `Map` внутрь `List` в данной задаче?
Я полагаю, что вам нужен либо список пар (объектов вроде `Map.Entry`), либо обычным `Map` можно обойтись. Пересмотрите свою задачу в сторону упрощения.

Comment: @iksuy нет, адаптеру действительно нужен лист мапов. Только это другая тема, и вообще тег **android**.

@expertgames вы спрашивали, как `JSON` превратить в `map`. Вам дан полный исчерпывающий ответ. Чтобы узнать, **как передать JSON в ListAdapter**, создайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Создаете класс с ключом, пишите геттеры - сеттеры. 
Помещаете их в лис и гоняете его через GSON. 
Он будет сам парсить из распарсивать это в json из с json'a.